# GitKraken: unable to open public key file

Tags: gitkraken

I installed GitKraken. Created a private and public key in the tab "General"

[image]

Then I connected Github and generated a new key.

[image]

When cloning a repository, GitKraken shows the necessary repositories.

[image]

I press the clone button. And shows an error

[image]

Please help me solve the problem. (Unable to open public key file)What's wrong?

Comment: So, do you have that key file? The question fails to mention that.

Comment: Educated guess: Do you have access rights to the directory in which the file was created?

Comment: I was experiencing this issue too - having a non-Latin character in the path cased it. So make sure nothing like that is in the path to the ssh files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have Russian letters in the folder name. Create a new ssh keys in another folder without Russian letters, or move existing ones.

I have same problem my solution:

1. Move .ssh folder from `C:/Users/%username%/` to `C:/Users/`

[image: git bash]

2. Setting up GitKraken

[image: gitkraken]